# How to get average for a column value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get average for a column

Name        Salary

HI         33168,00

Hello      32882,00

When I tried with below query

```
 select Name, Salary, Avg(Salary) as avg from table group by name, Salary
```

I'm getting Salary and Avg salary both same value.

expected result:

```
       Name         Salary       

        HI          33168,00    

        Hello       32882,00         

        avg         33025,00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by name and salary you will get one row for each such combination. In many cases this means that avg(salary) will be the same as salary. If you want to only get the average(salary) per name:

```
select Name, Avg(Salary) as avg from table group by name
```

If you want each individual salary as well you can do this with a union:

```
select Name, Avg(Salary) as salary from table group by name
union
select Name, Salary from table
```

A shortcut for the latter is:

```
select Name, Salary, Avg(Salary) as salary from table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Name, salary), (Name))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you group by [name] and [Salary], assuming your name is unique, you will get one average salary per [name], which will be the same as the salary value

```
select Avg(Salary) as avg from table
```

If you want detail and the average row, you could use a union all

```
   select name, Salary  from table
    UNION ALL 
    select 'Avg', Avg(Salary)  from table
```

Answer (score 2):

To get overall average of all `Salary` values, don't group the results at all:

```
select Avg(Salary) as avg from table
```

To get average of `Salary` for each `Name`, you have to group only by the `Name`, not by `Salary`:

```
select Name, Avg(Salary) as avg from table group by Name
```

This would calculate salary average for each Name that is present in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an average salary to your existing table, you can use `with rollup` (or `grouping sets`):

```
select coalesce(name, 'avg') as name, avg(salary) as salary
from table
group by name, salary with rollup;
```

The `avg(salary)` does nothing for the names, but it does allow the `with rollup` to add a row with the overall average.

If there are multiple rows per name, and you want the average of averages, you can do:

```
select coalesce(name, 'avg') as name, avg(salary) as salary
from table
group by name with rollup;
```